# How to handle events in SharePoint document library?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, remote-event-receiver

We are writing an application that handles events in document library.

Case1: When a new document is uploaded in library, Edit properties dialog opens and user clicks save after entering some property values. In this case we only get document item modified event and not getting document added event. We do get item checked out event though. How to get Item added event in this case or any way to identify item added event like based on the checked out event in conjunction with item version and date time?

Case2: When document is in Checked Out state if user edits the properties and saves the item then we are not getting the modified event. How to handle event if a checked out document is modified?